# eq() working against its definition

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Here is the code:

```
console.log($("div:eq(x)"))//[object Object]
```

I dont understand why the above code outputs **object object** ,even if you supply **y** in place of **x** it still works ,whatever you supply it still works. I'm a beginner to jquery, where have I made a mistake or misunderstood?

That **x** is simply undefined. Do eq accept anything, I thought only index it accept.

I got to this as I was trying to accomplish this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    $("<div>Helow</div>").appendTo(document.body);
    document.write("</br>");
    setInterval(waka,5000);
}

function waka(){          
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        $("div:eq(i)") //i want to select each div
    }
}
```

But each `div` is not getting selected at all. I assumed that `I` gets replaced with its numerical value.

Comment: That is not how jQuery selectors work.

Comment: `$("div:eq(" + i + ")")`, concentanation. Or just `$('div').eq(i)` !

Comment: @adeneo but why it returns object object

Comment: Because it's an object. What do you WANT it to return?

Comment: @Blazemonger but x above is undefined

Comment: `$("FOOBAR389652sdgjkqhk4h")` will return [object Object] too, because it is an object. `$()` ALWAYS returns an object. Also, `x` isn't being used as a variable, it's just a string the way you used it. Whether or not a variable named `x` is defined doesn't matter in that case.

Comment: Does'nt matter, a jQuery selector always returns an array like object, it's what that object contains that matters.

Comment: I suggest familiarizing yourself with the book "JavaScript: the Good Parts" or some other similar text, to strengthen your understanding of vanilla JavaScript before moving on to jQuery.

Comment: @Blazemonger - thank you, I'll do that ;-) ...

Comment: @adeneo Blazemonger is just being rude, you will learn javascript basics WHILE working with jQuery, since it's only a framework upon the language. It isn't a difference syntax. I learnt jQuery first, and in my opinion, it will make you think in a more efficient manner, especially in terms of object-oriented design.

Comment: @SSHThis - Me answering the comment was just a joke, Blazemongers comment wasn't directed at me (at least I think it wasn't) but the OP, I already know a little bit of javascript, at least I like to think I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think of $(param) as simply a function with param being a parameter. If you call a function that function can return anything - it doesn't have to tell you the parameter was invalid. So when jQuery interprets "div:eq(x)" it can't find it & just returns an empty instance of itself. It's not quite that simple but is enough to get you started in the right direction

Comment: @adeneo plz refer to this[http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/].The doc dont use this syntax $("div:eq(" + i + ")") to select the element ,but insteade uses the syntax i described in my question and i was suggested to use that one in the obove comment